# Specifying an arbitrary point on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-topology

It is known that any arbitrary point **x** on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ can be parametrised by the spherical coordinates
$$\bf{x}=r(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta),\quad 0\le\theta\le\pi,0\le\phi\le 2\pi.$$
Here the arbitrary point **x** appears to be a vector function on $\mathbb{R}^3$.See for instance Steward calculus (parametrisation of the unit sphere)

Now I know that the sphere is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I start asking and want to know a very elementary general fact...

Can any arbitrary point on a general manifold be viewed as a vector function on the corresponding Euclidean space? (Given the manifold can be embedded into that Euclidean space)

Comment: [Apparently,](http://mathoverflow.net/q/34658/5810) although there don't seem to be online references for that. $\;$

Comment: It is something written on my notes...

Comment: @math101 The function you gave is a map from $[0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi] \to \Bbb R^3$, which is one to one away from the endpoints. Are you asking that if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold in $\Bbb R^N$, is there a function $[0,1]^n \to \Bbb R^N$ onto your manifold that is one to one away from the boundary? (The answer to this question is yes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a manifold, a space $X$ has to be covered in coordinate maps $\varphi: A \subseteq \Bbb R^n \to X$. This is part of the definition. In particular, consider $\varphi$ to be a coordinate map onto a neighborhood of your point $x$. If $X$ is embedded into $R^m$ by some other map $\psi$, then $\psi \circ \varphi$ is a smooth map that could be considered a vector function.

Comment: I think you mean...if I let $V=\{(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta).$ and $x:V\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $\bf{x}(\theta,\phi)$ above. Clearly $\bf{x}(V)\subset\mathbb{S}^2$. $\bf{x}$ is a parametrisation of $\mathbb{S}^2$ and can be regarded as a vector function.